# Packages missing md5sums control file

Tags: 14.04, server, package-management, webmin, virtualmin

I just ran `sudo dpkg -C` on my server to check everything was ok. Unexpectedly, I got the following response:

```
The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
module-init-tools    transitional dummy package (module-init-tools to kmod)
libjson0:amd64       JSON manipulation library (transitional package)
```

I've been using Webmin / Virtualmin to manage the server up to this point and I'm still a relative newb to Linux and Ubuntu so I'm a little unsure of how serious an issue this is and how I can / should go about resolving it.

So, any help on this will be greatly appreciated.